# Merging multiple torrent files into one

Tags: networking, bittorrent, utorrent, merge, ktorrent

i have 10 **torrent** files and i haven't **downloaded** any one of them and i want to merge them into one big torrent file that download all the nested torrents within, i have read this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/511588/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-list-of-torrents-into-one-torrent-with-many-files-k) and seen this [tool](https://code.google.com/p/mergetorrent/) and all of these aim to merge uncompleted downloads !!, while i need to merge new un-downloaded ones, any help will be appreciated.
Yaser :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but there is no support in the `bittorrent-protocol` that makes it possible to do what you want to do.

Comment: is it possible that there is no way to do this even programmatically speaking ??

Comment: The bittorrent protocol is what it is and would need a major revision to make it possible to do what you want to do. Of course, a client could make it appear as if it only download it as one torrent, but that would only be an abstraction to that it in reality is downloading it as ten separate torrents.

Comment: this answers claims that it's possible using nested torrent files http://superuser.com/a/674338/285945  who's right?